# Print multiple pieces of a string at different times on a single line with formatting

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to print out some text on a single line dynamically, and format it to have 2 distinct columns that line up and have a minimum of 4 spaces in between them. I have seen the questions for formatting this when you can print everything out at the same time, but in this instance I will be copying files to a slow file share, so I'd like to print out the first status message, then execute the copy operation, and then print out the error or success message.

Here is my desired output:

```
Copying filename1...          complete.
Copying filename2...          complete.
Copying longerfilename3...    complete.
Copying f2...                 complete.
Copying f3...                 error: file not found.
```

And my operation order with pseudo code (this is inside a for loop):

```
try:
    print("Copying <filename>...", end = "")

    #copy operation here, may take awhile

    # Need some formatting help here
    print("success.")
except error:
    print("error.")
```

And my current output just looks like this:

```
Copying filename1... complete.
Copying file2... complete.
Copying f3... error: file not found.
```

Comment: Look up str.format() (or the older string % notation): https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatexamples

Comment: I did, but was trying to do {:>15}, which wasn't working. I see now I just needed left justification with enough space. Seems I was a little confused on how the numbers worked after specifying the justification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("Copying {:<30}".format("'{}' ...".format(filename)), end = "")
```